# Style elements when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Beginner here! I have 3 radio buttons each wrapped by a container and I'm trying to style the container when a radio button is selected using JS. I was able to change the border style of the container when a radio button is selected, but wasn't able to remove that border style when the other buttons were selected. How can I achieve this?

```js
const radioBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-btn')

radioBtns.forEach((radioBtn, index) => {

  const container = radioBtn.closest('.container');
  radioBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.add('highlight');
    if (!radioBtn.checked) {
      container.classList.remove('highlight');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container.highlight {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="radio" class="radio-btn">
</div>

<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="radio" class="radio-btn">
</div>

<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="radio" class="radio-btn">
</div>
```

Comment: Well to start, you're adding the click listener to each radio button, so they'll all do the same thing. No matter which radio button is clicked, as long as one of them is, the border will always be there because you can't "unselect" radio buttons. For that you would need a checkbox. You could, alternatively, make it so the radio button you want to give the border has a different click listener. That's all I've got for you.

Comment: Alternatively, you might be looking to "deselect" the other two radio buttons when one is clicked. If that's the case, you can do this programmatically in the JS, and then apply the style to the other boxes.

Comment: just add  the same `name` on your radio-inputs

Comment: In addition to the other comment, you need to specify the attribute `name` and make sure it's the same for all of them (eg: `name="car"`). This will make sure that only one radio button can be selected at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Your JS is ok... To work with checkboxes.

So why not use checkboxes? Ho, because you prefer the round looking radios, right? Then style your checkboxes to look like radios!

In the below snippet, I didn't touch the HTML *(execpt to change radios for checkboxes)* or the JS.

```js
const radioBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-btn')

radioBtns.forEach((radioBtn, index) => {

  const container = radioBtn.closest('.container');
  radioBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.add('highlight');
    if (!radioBtn.checked) {
      container.classList.remove('highlight');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.container.highlight {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,0.3)
}

input[type='checkbox']:before{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked:after{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  content: "";
  height: 9px;
  width: 9px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="checkbox" class="radio-btn">
</div>

<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="checkbox" class="radio-btn">
</div>

<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="checkbox" class="radio-btn">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you! The reason I chose radio buttons is I only want one option to be selected at a time

Comment: Well.. Then look for @Spectric answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with doing this simply by adding a few lines of code to your existing lines

```js
const radioBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-btn')

radioBtns.forEach((radioBtn, index) => {

  const container = radioBtn.closest('.container');
  const currentID = radioBtn.id;
  radioBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.add('highlight');
    radioBtns.forEach((rb, ind) => {
      if(rb.id == currentID) return;
      rb.closest('.container').classList.remove('highlight');
      rb.checked = false;
    });
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container.highlight {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" id="1">
</div>

<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" id="2">
</div>

<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" id="3">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked. However I did have to store the container of the radio buttons that are not selected after the if statement inside the second forEach loop. Otherwise the code will select the container of the selected radio button. Do you mind also explain why we need to assign ```false``` to ```rb.checked```? Thanks once again!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying you had to change, the rb.checked makes the other radio buttons "uncheck" so that only one is selected. Isn't this the behavior you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same name for each radio button so the user can only select one at a time.
Store the previous radio button in a variable, then remove the `highlight` class everytime a radio button is clicked.

```js
const radioBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-btn')
var prev;
radioBtns.forEach((radioBtn, index) => {

  const container = radioBtn.closest('.container');
  radioBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.add('highlight');
    if(prev != undefined){
      prev.closest('.container').classList.remove('highlight');
    }
    prev = radioBtn;
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container.highlight {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="radiobtn">
</div>

<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="radiobtn">
</div>

<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="radio" class="radio-btn" name="radiobtn">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this way

```js
const radioBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-btn')

radioBtns.forEach( (radioBtn,_,All) => 
  {
  radioBtn.onclick = _ =>
    {
    All.forEach(r=>r.closest('.container')
                     .classList.toggle('highlight', r.checked) )
    }
  })
```

```css
.container {
  border     : 1px solid black;
}

.container.highlight {
  border-color : green;
  background   : yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="radio" name="jojo" class="radio-btn">
</div>

<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="radio" name="jojo" class="radio-btn">
</div>

<div class=container>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <input type="radio" name="jojo" class="radio-btn">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

typically,these radio-btns can active only one.so these btns should in one group,we call that btn group like bootstrap do.
I would wrap a btn-group-container above all.when radio-btn clicked.it will search parent btn-group-container and then remove all highlight style under the btn-group-container,and add highlight style to the current btn-container.
hope this could help you.

Comment: Sorry! You're right I was missing the name attribute to these buttons and yes I want them to be in the same group so only one option could be selected